# Clean way to provide answer key to quiz with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, architecture, client-side

This is more about code organization and a slicker approach, that can be generalized. Specifically its in a Jeopardy Quiz that I'm building out to improve my skills in AJAX/JSON. I would like to keep the answers apart from the question. One can simply find and open the JSON in DevTools and find the correct answer. I'd like to make it a little harder, but not too hard to code or add any more layers past one or two JSON files. 
(And not overkill like hashing a DB query since its just a pet project).

Not sure how to do this... 
Here's my JSON..
        {
                            "question": "Town where Jefferson built Monticello", 
                            "choices": [
                                "Richmond",
                                "Raliegh",
                                "Charlottesville"
                            ]
                        }

I had the correct answer with the question in the JSON, but I'm not sure that is the best way to do this... I think an anwser key might be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this (and keep it simple) is to do a base64 encoding of your JSON object.

First, once you have all of your questions, encode them to base64. You can use the `btoa` function in JavaScript to do this. Don't put this line of code in your client though.

```
btoa( JSON.stringify({ "question": "Town where Jefferson built Monticello", "choices": [ "Richmond", "Raliegh", "Charlottesville" ] }))
```

Then, take that base64 encoded string and place it in your code.

```
const data = "eyJxdWVzdGlvbiI6IlRvd24gd2hlcmUgSmVmZmVyc29uIGJ1aWx0IE1vbnRpY2VsbG8iLCJjaG9pY2VzIjpbIlJpY2htb25kIiwiUmFsaWVnaCIsIkNoYXJsb3R0ZXN2aWxsZSJdfQ=="
```

From there, you can decode and turn it back into a JSON object in your code.

```
let questions = JSON.parse( atob(data) )
```

Like you mentioned in your question, this can still be "hacked". It's not proper security by any means. People can inspect it and run the code to get the questions and answers. However, the answers wouldn't be obvious at first glance.

To make it a little better, you can run your JavaScript through an obfuscation tool. The variables for `data` and `questions` would get mangled and it would be a bit harder to identify what is being decoded.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make an endpoint that gets the question id and the selected answer, returning whether or not it's correct and the correct answer, in case it's wrong, marking the question as answered for that user/session in the process.

That way, even if the user hits your API using DevTools or something like that, the effect would be the same as answering through the UI.

Comment: Hmm. At first when you said endpoint I thought you were simply sending the question ID and selected answer. If it responded with a 200 it would be right. But I didn't think about providing the correct answer at all as I didn't want to give away the answers so someone could just take it twice. ...But if the question bank grows big enough and they are randomized, it would make sense to provide correct answer and explanation. I will try your way.

Comment: That's why I mentioned marking that the person already answered that question. The concern you raised would be the same as if the user tried answering the question several times through the UI. Some kind of session management would be the simplest way to handle that, in my opinion. As for returning the correct answer or not, it's a matter of the UX you're going for. I'd do it this way, but you can just as well only show that the answer is wrong. I've seen online quizzes taking both approaches.